# Structuring simple PHP for-each loop from array

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array called `$user_ids` that prints as:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [user_id] => 2 ) )
```

I want to perform `send_msg` for every `user_id` in the array. In the example above, I want to achieve the equivalent of this:

```
send_msg( 1, $body_input, $subject_input);  
send_msg( 2, $body_input, $subject_input);
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't work.

```
foreach ($user_ids as $user_N){
send_msg( $user_N, $body_input, $subject_input);    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP >= 7.0.0 you can extract all of the `user_id`s from the objects with `array_column`:

```
foreach(array_column($user_ids, 'user_id') as $user_N) {
    send_msg($user_N, $body_input, $subject_input);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// You're looping over objects; not user IDs
foreach ($user_ids as $obj){
    send_msg( $obj->user_id, $body_input, $subject_input);    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array with objects. To get the ID in your loop, you must use `$user_N->user_id` so change your loop to:

```
foreach ($user_ids as $user_N){
    send_msg( $user_N->user_id, $body_input, $subject_input);    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

looks like you converted a JSON to ARRAY without passing second parameter to true and that is why you have array of objects.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

In this case you can do

```
send_msg( $user_N->user_id, $body_input, $subject_input);
```

But if you convert JSON to associated array(by passing second param to **true**), then you can do

```
send_msg( $user_N['user_id'], $body_input, $subject_input);
```